# Issue with GameNetwork and Corona SDK

Tags: lua, coronasdk

[image]

From the picture above in matchDataListener function in line 225, the question is what is the meaning of matchDataEvent.data.data. I have already explored to the reference in http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/GameNetwork/match.html but there is no any explanation.

I also don't understand the meaning of

```
for i = 1, #matchDataEvent.data.participants, 1
```

in line 244

Could anyone explain them to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `matchDataEvent.data.data` refers to the string inside `matchDataEvent.data` table/array. I've no idea about what it generally contains though. The **line #225** in particular; checks if this string exists and in not empty.
2. In `#matchDataEvent.data.participants`, the `#` is the `__len` method which returns the length of the table/array `matchDataEvent.data.participants`. Total number of participants are returned (a number). This number is used as the max value in the `for` loop.